# Why does the use of ... in any expression in a function cause the value of arg to be nil in Lua?

Tags: function, lua, arguments, variadic-functions

```
function tell(num,...)
    print("value of implicit table:",arg)
    --print("value of implicit table:",...)
    select(1,arg)
    --select(1,...)
end
tell(12,43,12,55)
```

Why is it that using `...` in an expression causes the value of `arg` to
be `nil` e.g. with `print("value of implicit table:",...)` or `select(1,...)`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lua 5.1 officially deprecates the use of the `arg` table for varargs, preferring `...`. However, there is a compile time option for Lua itself, `LUA_COMPAT_VARARG`, to permit the use of `arg` in 5.1 code.

If `LUA_COMPAT_VARARG` was defined when Lua was compiled, an `arg` table will be created in varargs functions, and populated with the arguments - unless the compiler detects the use of `...` inside the function. In that case, it assumes that you're using 5.1 style varargs instead of 5.0, and doesn't create the table. It *does*, however, still create the local named `arg`!

The upshot of this is that if `LUA_COMPAT_VARARG` is defined, vararg functions that don't use `...` in the body get a `local arg` containing the argument list, and vararg functions that *do* get a `local arg` containing `nil`. This bug is present in all versions of 5.1 and means, in particular, that you can't access a global or upvalue named `arg` from any varargs functions if `LUA_COMPAT_VARARG` was defined at compile time.

Lua 5.2 drops support for `arg`-style varargs entirely and thus does not have this issue regardless of how it was configured at compile time.

(Source: the changes in varargs handling between 5.0 and 5.1, and the `LUA_COMPAT_VARARG` option, are mentioned in [the Lua 5.1 reference manual, section 7.1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#7.1). The manual refers you to [luaconf.h](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/luaconf.h.html). The exact behaviour is not documented anywhere, as far as I'm aware of; it can be determined experimentally, by reading [lparser.c](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lparser.c.html) and [ldo.c](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/ldo.c.html), or from the posts on the mailing list that originally reported this issue.)

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. I've tried it with lua 5.2.0 and got this : `table: 00899618` as `args` value(confirms what you said). By "compile time", do you mean when compiling the lua interpreter or when compiling a lua script using `luac.exe`. How does one get to know about such details?

Comment: @Segfault he means when the interpreter is built from source and something like `-DLUA_COMPAT_VARARG` is provided to the C compiler etc.

Comment: `-DLUA_COMPAT_ALL` is in the makefile. I guess the `_ALL` means `LUA_COMPAT_VARARG` is included. Is this information in the documentation or something?

Comment: @Segfault it's documented-ish - the manual and the comments in `luaconf.h` mention it, the exact specifics of the behaviour (e.g. the way it creates a local named `arg` even in `...` mode) are not documented anywhere that I'm aware of. I've edited the question to include links to the relevant sources.

As for `LUA_COMPAT_ALL`, that's [specific to 5.2](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/luaconf.h.html) and enables all backwards-compatibility options when defined.