# Strange if statement in Lua

Tags: if-statement, lua

Okay so I am new to the Lua language so this could be a super stupid question, but I have come across the following statement and I have no idea what it means (even after some searching)

```
if (...) then

   -- Doing some stuff

end
```

What does the `...` mean?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679174/why-does-the-use-of-in-any-expression-in-a-function-cause-the-value-of-arg-t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`...` is used in [vararg functions](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.9).  Its value is a list of all the "extra" arguments (i.e. those that follow the last named argument of the current function.)

`(...)` (like any other expression in parentheses) adjusts the result to one value (the first one in the list.)

So that `if` statement effectively means "if the first variadic argument exists and is not `false` or `nil`."

Examples:

```
local function f1(...)
  if (...) then
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end

local function f2(x, ...)
  if (...) then
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end

print(f1())       -- false
print(f1(1))      -- true
print(f1(1, 2))   -- true
print(f1(1, nil)) -- true
print(f1(nil, 2)) -- false

print(f2())       -- false
print(f2(1))      -- false
print(f2(1, 2))   -- true
print(f2(1, nil)) -- false
print(f2(nil, 2)) -- true
```

At the top level (i.e. not inside a `function . . . end` form) it still works the same way, but the current function is a *chunk* (i.e. script or module.)

If it is a module, `(...)` gives the module name.  But then the `if(...)` test would not be useful because the first argument is always a string.

If it's a script, `(...)` gives the first command-line argument (and the `if(...)` tests whether any arguments were given.)

Comment: I would note that `if (...) then` does exactly the same as `if ... then` since the statement itself adjusts the list to one element anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`...` is used in the function parameter to indicate that the function is variadic. It can be used inside the function as an expression, representation the function's extra arguments.

For instance, this function takes a fixed argument plus variable arguments:

```
function vafun(num, ...)
    if (...) then
        for _, v in ipairs{...} do
            print(v)
        end
    else
        print("empty var")
    end
end
```

The `if(...)` tests if the variable arguments part is empty.

```
vafun(3, 4, 5)
vafun(3)
vafun()
```

Output:

```
4
5
empty var
empty var
```